# Integrating facebook connect in my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Ok, I've already have an exisiting web application. The back end is a rest interface. Initially, to login, the user had to register and then login with his credentials. But i want to integrate the facebook login;

so in my rest Interface i'm adding two more methods

1. `registerfbUser`:registers the user account
2. `loginfbUser`:allows a user to use his facebook account to login into the system after
   getting registered

I've been able to use facebook connect and the graph api to connect to facebook. Now, the loginfbUser will be called using ajax and details will be provided in the JSON format.

My problem is that what information should i pass to the method `loginfbUser` to authenticate the facebook user. I cannot pass only the facebook id, because the api will be open and thus anybody will be able to make a POST request with the facebook id in json format

Comment: Do you want to allow users to login the old way as well? Will new users have the choice of logging in either the new way or the old way?

Comment: yes of course, both ways

Answer (score 2):

At our company, we extensively use FB's authentication through AJAX to "log-in" users. The way we do it is simple. After the user "logs-in" or authenticates through FB's JS SDK on the page, we send the access token to our server in an AJAX call. This access token is then cross-verified by our server by sending a /me api call to graph.facebook.com and getting the FB id from there. By doing this, we are SURE that it is this person and this person only.

Once this is done, we store this information (access token and the user's facebook id) is a server side session and hence all future calls within this same session will recognize the user correctly.

If you starting point is a FB App Tab or a canvas app, then the access token and the fbId is sent by facebook in a signed request which you can "unsign" and use to store in the session and avoid having to make that call to graph.facebook.com (which can be a bit slow and form a performance/UX bottleneck)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the whole point of Facebook Connect is to allow web developers to stop worrying about usernames/passwords. I believe the idea is to store the Facebook ID in the database of users and use the Graph API to see if that user is currently logged in in Facebook or not. In that way, your website authenticates the user via its presence on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the JS SDK and the PHP SDK, any function that performs an action which requires FB authentication should start like  this:

```
$this->_facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $this->app_id,
  'secret' => $this->app_secret,
  'fileUpload' => true, 
  'cookie' => true
));

try {
  $this->_fb_userid = $this->_facebook->getUser();
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  // the user is not authenticated!
  return;
}

try {
  $this->_fb_me = $this->_facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  // API call didn't work, show error...
  return;
}
```

If your user authenticates via javascript, the PHP SDK will automatically know about the logged in user. The JS SDK sends this info via a cookie to your server and the PHP SDK reads it automatically.